# Python: Incorrect dictionary encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm making a dictionary which contains words containing characters like `č,ě,á` (Czech alphabet). When I try to print these words into the console before adding to dictionary, I can see correct encoded words. The problem is that when I add it to the dictionary and print the word as it's value, I see it but in wrong encoding. Here is a printscreen of my console, the first row is `print name` and the second row is `print dict`.

[image]

These words / sentences should be the same.

Info:

***PyCharm IDE, Python 2.7.8, default encoding: "utf-8"***

Thank you for your advices!

EDIT: Attaching the code ('url' is the url of the web page):

```
    def getSoup(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'xml')
    return soup

a=0
klubyDict = dict()
index = getSoup("url")
all = index.findAll('A')
for i in all:

    okres = getSoup("http://url%s"%(i['HREF']))
    kluby = okres.findAll('A')
    # print(kluby[0]['HREF'])
    print "Okrsok...%s"%(i.text)
    for klub in kluby:
        klubHtml = getSoup("http://url%s"%(klub['HREF']))
        name = klub.text
        print name
        emailTag = klubHtml.find('td',text=re.compile("Email:"))
        email = emailTag.text[7:]
        if len(name)>0:
            klubyDict[name]=email if len(email)>0 else "email nezadany"
            print klubyDict

print "Saving to file..."
with open('futbaloveKluby','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(klubyDict,f)
```

EDIT2: Adding the data into the excel file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cPickle as pickle

dict = dict()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Futbal.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

with open('futbaloveKluby','rb') as f:
    dict = pickle.load(f)

colKlub = 0
colEmail = 1
row = 0

for klub in dict.keys():
    worksheet.write(row,colKlub, klub)
    worksheet.write(row,colEmail, dict[klub])
    row += 1

workbook.close()
        print table.text
```

The main thing is that after this code, I put values of this dictionary into the Excel table using xlscWriter. When I open Excel file I can see wrong characters.

Comment: did you use `utf8 encoding` in top of your main code ? or how you pass your `unicode` to `dictionary`?

Comment: @Kasra Yes, I've stated on the top of the file utf-8

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: One of those is the `repr` of a python `dict` and the other is `print` output.  Please post some code to help understand what you're doing rather than a fragment of a screenshot ;-)

Comment: @rob Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: so how you pass your unicode to dictionary pls show your code !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Rob What am I doing wrong. I want to put values of the dictionary into the Excel using xlscWriter, but when I do it and open the xlc file, there is a wrong encoding.

Comment: If your question is "what am I doing wrong when I use xslcWriter?", then you'll have to show what you are doing? Without seeing the relevant code, any answer is just a guess. Please create a new program, which is the **smallest**, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. You should be able to demonstrate the problem with xlscWriter in five to seven lines. Copy-paste that entire program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: And, by the way, do you mean [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/)?

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, I do. According to your comment: You can see in the EDIT2 the way I'm using xlscWriter. When I open the excel file I can see for example 'Tìlovýchovná' instead of 'Tělovýchovná'

Comment: I am not able to run the code in the EDIT2. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

`import codecs` and use this code for your name :

```
name = klub.text
print name.decode('utf-8')
```